# Adding criteria to a Linq query dynamically

Tags: linq-to-entities

What is the best way to build-up a dynamic query when some of the fields you want to filter on are not part of the returned result set.

The fictitious example below should demonstrate what I want to achieve, but I obviously can't filter on the reviewer in this way because it's not part of the result set. So can I achieve that in a dynamic way? There are multiple filters that might (and crucially might not) be applied to the query.

Whereas I could use an OR condition, it feels much cleaner to just apply the criteria that is required... but maybe that isn't possible?

```
IQueryable<TblProduct> query = from p in db.TblProduct
                   join r in db.TblReview on p.ProductID equals r.ProductID
                   select p;

// ...Other optional filters...

if (filterReviewerID.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.ReviewerID == filterReviewerID.Value);
}
```

Comment: One way is to define your initial LINQ query so that it *does* include the columns that you need to filter on. Then once you have applied any/all of the dynamic filters, perform a final `.Select()` to extract just the data that you need. If you really need to filter on an *exists* condition (as your case appears to be), I believe you can omit the  referenced table from the original query and structure your condition as something like `.Where(p => db.TblReview.Any(r => r.ProductID == p.ProductID && r.ReviewerID == filterReviewerID.Value)`.